# How do I read this mapping document?

Tags: etl, talend

I am new to etl and am working with talend. I was given this document and was told to make an "extraction job." how exactly do I read this document for this talend job that I have to make?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, `ETL` basically means, Extract-Transform-Load.
From your example, I can understand that you have to create a Target table which will pull data from the Source table based on certain conditions. These conditions are mentioned in your image.

You basically have to look at the `Source File` columns from you image. They clearly state,

1.) `File(Table name)`, this means which table from the Source DB this attribute is flowing in.

2.) `Attribute(s) (Field Name)` : This is the name of the column.

3.) `Extract logic` : This means what logic has to be applied while extracting this column from Source(`Straight Move`) means, just dump the source value in Target.

This is just to get you started, as nobody will actually create the whole ETL flow for you here.